# Непонятный GridBagLayout. Кнопки и размеры. Правильная компановка GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout, jpanel

Создаю текстовую игру. Проблема в окне с самими действиями в игре.
Хочется, что бы окно выглядело так:[image: Эскиз желаемого экрана]
Для этого я решил использовать GridBagLayout, но его работа мне не понятна,
потому что при использовании следующего кода:

Класс GamePanel

```
public class GamePanel extends JPanel {

    JTextArea txtGameLog;
    NavigatePanel navigatePanel;
    InfoPanel infoPanel;

    public GamePanel() {
        setBackground(new Color(200, 120, 90));

        txtGameLog = new JTextArea();
        navigatePanel = new NavigatePanel();
        infoPanel = new InfoPanel();

        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.weightx = 1;
        gbc.weighty = 0.1;

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.gridwidth = 2;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_START;
        add(txtGameLog, gbc);

        gbc.weighty = 0.25;

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LAST_LINE_START;
        add(infoPanel, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LAST_LINE_END;
        add(navigatePanel, gbc);
    }
}

class NavigatePanel extends JPanel {
    GameButton btnNorth;
    GameButton btnSouth;
    GameButton btnWest;
    GameButton btnEast;

    public NavigatePanel() {
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        setBackground(Color.GRAY);

        btnNorth = new GameButton(Localization.getString("ui.game.btnNorth"));
        btnSouth = new GameButton(Localization.getString("ui.game.btnSouth"));
        btnWest = new GameButton(Localization.getString("ui.game.btnWest"));
        btnEast = new GameButton(Localization.getString("ui.game.btnEast"));

        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;

        gbc.weightx = 1;
        gbc.weighty = 1;

        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_END;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.gridwidth = 2;
        add(btnNorth, gbc);

        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        add(btnWest, gbc);

        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        add(btnEast, gbc);

        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_START;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        gbc.gridwidth = 2;
        add(btnSouth, gbc);

    }
}
```

Класс InfoPanel

```
class InfoPanel extends JPanel {

    JLabel lblGrenade;
    JLabel lblTreasure;
    GameButton btnMenu;

    public InfoPanel() {
        setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        btnMenu = new GameButton(Localization.getString("ui.game.btnMenu"));
        add(btnMenu, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
}
```

Класс GameButton

```
public class GameButton extends JButton{
    public GameButton(String name){
        super(name);
        setBackground(new Color(190, 170, 155));
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(60, 60));
        setMaximumSize(new Dimension(60, 60));
        setSize(60, 60);
        setAlignmentX(CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    }
}
```

Получается следующее:
[image: Скриншот экрана который получился]
Это почти, то, что я хочу. Но пропорции размещения панелей и расстояния между кнопками неправильное. Как сгруппировать кнопки как на первой картинке и как правильно задать пропорции? Как работает `gbc.weightx` и `gbc.weighty`?

и немного оффтоп:
здесь есть сворачиваемый спойлер?

Comment: При всём этом непонятно почему кнопки сжимаются, хотя им в конструкторе жёстко задан размер. как это решить?

Answer (score 1):

Я бы сделала так (`GamePanel`):

```
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbc.weightx = 1;
    gbc.weighty = 1;

    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    gbc.gridwidth = 2;
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
    add(txtGameLog, gbc);

    gbc.weighty = 0;
    gbc.weightx = 1;

    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    gbc.gridwidth = 1;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LAST_LINE_START;
    add(infoPanel, gbc);

    gbc.weighty = 0;
    gbc.weightx = 0;

    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    gbc.gridwidth = 1;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LAST_LINE_END;
    add(navigatePanel, gbc);
```

Comment: Здорово, почти то что хотел, но как же сделать кнопки квадратными?

Comment: и всё же хочется кнопки побольше и повыше. [То что получилось](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kL2K3.png)

Comment: Думаю, для этого нужно менять `NavigatePanel`.

Comment: На что и как? В коде этот класс добавил с самого начала. Пожалуйста подскажите.